# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

I have started learning dagger 2 dependency injection. For that I'm following a video tutorial and [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android).

I have done what is written on the guide but facing this error. The error happens when I'm using **kotlin-kapt** plugin.

Please help me solve/understand the issue so that I can further my learning. I'm completely stuck.

The problem happens when using kapt. I have tried not using kapt and the project builds without an error. But then IDEA does not find the Dagger Component. For example.

```
@Component
Interface UserRegistrationComponent{...}
```

```
val regComponent = DaggerUserRegistrationComponent.builder().build() // this does not work

// DaggerUserRegistrationComponent does not appear in the suggestions.
```

Here's my build.gradle(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.waesh.daggerexample'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.waesh.daggerexample"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def dagger_version = "2.47"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    // implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger_version"
    // implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$dagger_version" // if you use the support libraries
    // annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger_version"
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```